# How do i delete random characters from a string?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using python and firebase. My code recieves a variable from firebase with the information i need and some exra info so i would like to know how to delete that part of the variable. The perfect way should be deleting some characters from the right and some characters from the left, but most part of the variable is random.
This is the code

```
frame = firebase.get("/LogFirebase/Frame//", None)
print(frame)
```

and this is what i get from the console

```
{'-M4Wghe_NLwGVOQ57K2f': {'frame': 'newframes'}}
```

I want to delete the first 36 characters and the last 2

Comment: The frame appears to be a dictionary, not a string. If you want to get `newframes`, you can just do `frame['-M4Wghe_NLwGVOQ57K2f']['frame']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to extract `'-M4Wghe_NLwGVOQ57K2f'` and `newframes` respectively, then you can simply use dictionary methods to extract information.

```py
# These should both be strings
# They will have 
first_info = list(frame.keys())[0]
second_info = list(frame.values())[0]['frame']
```

This should help you to get the information you need granted that info is the two things I assumed above. Let me know if this was a correct assumption.

Comment: If i add that 2 lines the code gets an error: AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'.    I want to get only the value that is in the "newframe" place. Also the part from '-M4X-CskK7JQT9VQHJ_-" is constantly changing.

Comment: Also it´s my first time using stack overflow so i dont really know how to use it in a good way :)

Comment: No worries. is `'-M4Wghe_NLwGVOQ57K2f'` (or its constantly changing value always in place of `random_string` : `{random_string: {'frame': 'newframe'}}`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uFlcQablQj0NfXmJ12x8Ky57ZAUwvBW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so are you trying to extract the 'newframes'

Comment: then just do `list(frame.values())[0]['frame']`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'    Im using python 3

Comment: That means that you are not getting anything from your Firebase database. I copied your input given in the original post and ran my command and it seems to return 'newframes'

Comment: I do because if i print(frame) the info i uploaded to database is showed

Comment: so `list(frame.values())[0]['frame']` is giving you an attribute error?

Comment: Instead of print(frame) I put print(list(frame.values())[0]['frame']) and it gave me the last error

Comment: can you do `print(type(frames))` and let me know what it returns.

Comment: On my end, based on your inputs that you provided, my solution should work. im confused as to why you are getting a Name error when you defined `frames = firebase.get("string", None)`

Comment: Wait I ve just put print(type(frame)) and it returned me <<class "NoneType">

Comment: if frame is of `NoneType` value that means that variable has no value. There must be something wrong. Can you try printing frame again because if it is of `NoneType` then it should print out `None`

Comment: Ok I revised my code and there was an error I'm sorry. Now it returns <class "dict">

Comment: no worries it happens. now can you try rerunning the line i gave you before: `list(frame.values())[0]['frame']`

Comment: OH THANKS now it works. Just because of that error list(frame.values())[0]["frames"] wasn't working. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: yeah no problem! glad I could help. Whenever you get the time, mark this as the correct answers for future visitors. Stay safe!!